# Rails dynamically remove text field not working on modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have added dynamically add input fields in modal pop-up by using **Rails-casts** episode 196. But when I try to remove added input field the modal pop-up got disappear.

**Application Helper**

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
```

**View**

```
<div class="col-md-5">
                  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#buglistmodal">Click to add bugs list</a>
                  <div class="modal fade bannerformmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="bannerformmodal" aria-hidden="true" id="buglistmodal">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Bug list</h4>
                          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <div class="row">
                            <%= f.fields_for :bug_fixes do |builder| %>
                              <%= render 'bug_fix_fields', f: builder %> 
                            <% end %>
                            <%= link_to_add_fields '<i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i>'.html_safe, f, :bug_fixes %>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

**Render file -> _bug_fix_field.html.erb**

```
<div class="row col-md-11" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= f.text_field :bug_id, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Bug ID" %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= f.text_area :summary, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Description" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x"></i>'.html_safe, "#", class: "remove_fields" %>
</div>
```

**JQuery which I have included**

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('form').on('click', '.remove_fields', function(event) {
      $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1');
      $(this).closest('fieldset').hide();
      return event.preventDefault();
    });
    return $('form').on('click', '.add_fields', function(event) {
      var regexp, time;
      time = new Date().getTime();
      regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g');
      $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time));
      return event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

Note: The above Jquery was added at the bottom of the view page.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: maybe you could use cocoon gem. But I understand the fun in brewing your own solution. The click-handlers seem correct at first glance.

But, imho you are looking for the nearest `fieldset` to remove, yet the nested items are not wrapped in a `fieldset`. Not sure why it then ends up removing the modal.

The easiest solution imho is to wrap the nested bug-fixes in a specific class and then you can just search for the nearest instance of that class to remove (that's how we solve it in cocoon).